# jquery foreach for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i have jquery for disable buttons 
if check box checked then button  enabled

```
document.getElementById('disabler').onchange = function() {   
                        if ($(disabler).is( ":checked" ) ){
                            $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false);
                            $("#signin_submit").css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
                        }  else { 
                        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', true);
                        $("#signin_submit").css( 'cursor', 'not-allowed' );
                        }
                    }
                     });
```

there is many checkbox but this code work only for first check box only !

Comment: what is the value of `disabler`?

Comment: Why are you doing `document.getElementById('disabler').onchange` while you already have jQuery?

Comment: its just id name `<input type="checkbox" name="delgl[]" id="disabler" value="<?= $u->id ?>" />`

Comment: I think you are using same `id` for multiple checkbox , use `class` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).on("change", "<selector for disablers>", function() {   
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#signin_submit").css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else { 
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#signin_submit").css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
    }
});
```

`<selector for disablers>` should probably be a class (`.disabler`) rather than id, since you said you have many of them.

Answer (score 1):

*there is many checkbox but this code work only for first check box only !*

**IDs must be unique.**. You should class instead.

Example of using class selector

```
$('.disabler').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else {
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', true).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use only jQuery:

```
$('#disabler').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }  else { 
        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', true).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
         $("#disabler").change(function(){ 
                    if ($("#disabler").is( ":checked" ) ){
                        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false);
                        $("#signin_submit").css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
                    }  
                  else { 
                        $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', true);
                        $("#signin_submit").css( 'cursor', 'not-allowed' );
                   }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one `disabler` in you page, firstly you should use `class` attribute instead of `ID`, then easily do this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".disabler", function(){
    //your stuff
});
```

ID attribute is used as a `unique` identifier.

check this working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZX6A/);

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you are already using jQuery, so use it.

However, and in addition, you are calling the jQuery object far too many times.  If you are parsing through to get the jQuery object more than once, then you should create local variables.

Second, you might consider using the power of closures for things like this:

```
function wireDisabler() {
    // closures
    var $cbxDisabler = $('#disabler');
    var $btnSubmit = $("#signin_submit");
    var fOnChange = function() {
        var bChecked = $cbxDisabler.is(':checked');
        $btnSubmit.prop('disabled', !bChecked)
            .css('cursor', (bChecked ? 'pointer' : 'not-allowed'));
    };
    // handle event
    $cbxDisabler.change(fOnChange);
}
```